# Error getting path from a file inside a jar file within ear because a colon :

Tags: java, file, jar, path, ear

Environment:

- windows (but should work on linux as well)
- java 11
- jboss 7.2
- jar within ear

app.ear
|
app-commons.jar
|
resources
|
mailing
|
Template.html
app-back.war
|
Service.java(to access Template.html)

I am tryin to read an html file within a jar inside an ear. But Path is getting an invalid path because of an ':'

Any idea to fix this?

**Error log**

```
2021-08-10 13:28:37,480 SEVERE [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.context] (default task-32) javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: javax.ejb.EJBException: java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: Illegal char <:> at index 2: /C:/dev/servers/jboss-eap-7.2/bin/content/app.ear/lib/accfor-commons.jar/mailing/Template.html
...
Caused by: java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: Illegal char <:> at index 2: /C:/dev/servers/jboss-eap-7.2/bin/content/app.ear/lib/ap-commons.jar/mailing/Template.html
...
```

**Code Service.java**

```
public String obtainMailTmpl(MessageType type) throws IOException {
    Path path = Paths.get(new MyPath().getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(type.templateFile).getPath());
    return Files.readString(path);
}
```

Comment: Not sure that's possible, but you could try `InputStream in = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/ap-commons.jar!/mailing/Template.html");`